# URL Rewrite Issue for Print button

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, joomla, url-rewriting

I have a website which is developed using Joomla. I am using Joomla's Default URL rewriting option.

On one page I have this URL before SEF enable.

```
index.php?option=com_osproperty&task=property_details&id=19
```

after SEF Enabled it becomes..

```
component/osproperty/?no_html=1
```

I want to skip this URL to become SEO Friendly. Because due to this, I am not able to use print functionality.

Comment: Why did this question get protected?

Comment: @cppl: Spam answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The router.php file for your com_osproperty is not properly written to address print links. You will need to fix that file. Take a look at how the com_content router is written.